# Как паодключить Jar-файл(стороннюю бибилиотеку) в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, библиотеки, jar, зависимости, настройка

Всем привет.

У меня есть [проект](https://github.com/DEGTEVUWU/java-project-78), я сделал из него Jar-файл и теперь хочу подключить эту библиотеку так сказать в другие проекты.

У меня получается сделать это на простых программах из одного класса, я использую

```
java -cp  app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar App.java
```

, где `app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` - имя моекго джарника, а
`App.java` - имя тестового класса

Проблема в том, что я не нахожу легкого способа добавить это файл в IDEA, чтоб это было легко и кжадый человек мог нажать две кнопки, сделать импорт и пользоваться методами моей бибилиотеки.
Я делаю сделующее:
File -> Project Structure -> Libraries -> + -> Java -> My Jar-file -> Apply -> Ok

Также я добавил этот файл в Modules -> Dependencies

В итоге, когда я делаю импорт (мой импорт выглядит, как  `import hexlet.code.Validator;`  ) IDEA подсвечивает его красным и пишет `add library to classpath`, я жму и ничего не проихсодит

Помогите с решением проблемы, пж

Comment: Использовать Maven или Gradle

Comment: Привет, а можно чуть больше подробностей?

Comment: Вам нужно использовать так называемые Сборщики приложений. Они включают в себя функционал по управлению зависимостями. Почитайте, посмотрите видео.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался.

Использовал для Gradle-Kotlin build system, добавьте в файл build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
   implementation(files("libs/имя_файла.jar"))
}
```